# Java 2D MouseListener and Timer questions

Tags: java, swing, timer, mouselistener

I am writing a game that paints rectangles one at a time (given a time interval specified by a timer) without destroying previously painted rectangles, and when the player clicks on the rectangle, it should disappear and the score should increase.

The rectangles should continue to appear on the JPanel whether or not the player clicked on anything.

But right now I cannot seem to get the rectangles to appear one at a time and I cannot seem to remove the specific rectangles that the player clicks.

Here is the JPanel that does the drawing (I have another class that uses a JFrame to include this JPanel):

```
class Surface extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener
{
    private double[] xcorr = new double[20];
    private double[] ycorr = new double[20];
    private Rectangle2D.Double[] rectangles = new Rectangle2D.Double[20];
    private int count = 0;
    private int score = 0;

    public Surface()
    {
        initRectangles();

        initTimer();

        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    private void initRectangles()
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++)
        {
            xcorr[i] = r.nextDouble() * (500-50);
            ycorr[i] = r.nextDouble() * (500-50);
            rectangles[i] = new Rectangle2D.Double();
            rectangles[i].setFrame(xcorr[i], ycorr[i], 50, 50);
        }
    }

        private void initTimer()
    {
        Timer timer;
                timer = new Timer(1000, this);
                timer.setInitialDelay(200);
                timer.start();
        }

    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        count++;

        repaint(); // this is where I want the next Rectangle to be painted without destroying any previously painted rectangle
        }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
    {
        double x = me.getX();
        double y = me.getY();

        for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++)
        {
            if (x > xcorr[i] && x < xcorr[i] + 50 && y > ycorr[i] && y < ycorr[i] + 50)
            {
                score++;

                remove(rectangles[i]); // this is where I want the rectangle that the player clicked to disappear
            }
        }
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {}

        private void doDrawing(Graphics g)
        {
                initRectangles();

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

                RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                rh.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

                g2d.setRenderingHints(rh);

                g2d.setColor(new Color(150, 150, 150));

                g2d.draw(rectangles[count]);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
                doDrawing(g);
        }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: super.paintComponent as 1st code line inside paintComponent can solve this issue

Comment: the Timer issue or the removing rectangle issue?

Comment: super.paintComponent removing, clear all paiting, otherwise painting cumulated

Comment: just tried it, super.paintComponent removes the rectangle that was previously painted without the player clicking on it?

Comment: not tried your code, but for animations or movement is neccesary, have to wait for answerer(s) with real skills with Painting in Swing, but you can to click to the paintComponent tag, there are bunch of code in MCVE form

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).